# How to create an UIImageView extension that is rounded by itself

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I've been experiencing an annoying problem recently.

Assume I want to use an image in multiple places across my application, and everywhere it has to be **rounded so as to be a circle**.
Because I want my code to be clean, I think that this functionality (of rounding itself) should be put **inside** the class extending UIImageView.
I have created a simple class that overrides storyboard constructor and is responsible for setting cornerRadius properly:

```
class RoundedImageView: UIImageView {


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/2
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

For constraints like

- width : 100,
- height : 100

  this obviously works, as the frame is not changed after the constructor is called (because it has correct dimensions in storyboard). The problem occurs when, for example,  the constraints look like this:
- width equals to 0.5 superview's
- aspect ratio: 1:1

because the frame changes after the constructor is called.

What I ended up doing is something like this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    myRoundedImageInstance.layer.cornerRadius = ...
}
```

in every view controller that has the instance of this class inside...
...which works, because the frame is recalculated after the imageView changes dimensions but this is **ugly**, and existence of the class seems to be **unnecessary in this case**.

I tried putting frame's recalculation in drawRect - doesn't work either.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why not move your rounding code to `RoundedImageView.layoutSubviews`? Another option is to set your layer mask to a circular path.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about this method (layoutSubviews) for views, not view controllers. Should I call super in this method? Your answer solved the problem btw. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Because I want my code to be clean, I think that this functionality (of rounding itself) should be put inside the class extending UIImageView" I don't see why. Why don't you put the functionality inside UIImage, i.e. the image _itself_ crops itself to a circle?

Comment: I made it an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move your circle updating code into your `layoutSubviews` method.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple example that is IBDesignable (You can see what it will look like in the interface builder)

```
@IBDesignable
    class RoundedUIImageView: UIImageView {
        @IBInspectable var round: Bool = true {
            didSet {
                self.clipsToBounds = true
                self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width / 2
                self.layer.borderWidth = 2.5
                self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(rgba: "#D0D0D0").CGColor
            }
        }
    }
```

You can make it more complex, since this assumes that the UIImageView is a square. If it isn't, it will end up being an ellipse. You could calculate the minimum size, then clip that way. But this is the most simple form of what you are trying to do.

EDIT: Same idea, but the code is more refined.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RoundedUIImageView: UIImageView {
    @IBInspectable var round: Bool = true {
        didSet { self.setNeedsLayout() }
    }

    @IBInspectable var width: CGFloat = 2.5 {
        didSet { self.setNeedsLayout() }
    }

    @IBInspectable var color: UIColor = UIColor(rgba: "#D0D0D0") {
        didSet { self.setNeedsLayout() }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.clipsToBounds = true

        if round {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width / 2
        } else {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        }

        self.layer.borderWidth = self.width
        self.layer.borderColor = self.color.CGColor
    }
}
```

It has defaults, so everything can be consistent. But it is customizable through the storyboard too.

Comment: It's really cool (the IBDesignable stuff), the only problem is that it doesn't answer my question. Not only doesn't it react to layout changes (calculating frames from constraints) but also requires me to set this value by hand every time I use the class (because setting it to true by default won't call didSet - I checked it). The correct answer is the first comment to my question.

Comment: I updated my answer to be more specific for what I was trying to explain.